# Jquery validation and scrolltop Not working

Tags: jquery

I have tried this jquery validation for registration page... When i click submit the error box shows..... I have two issues with this..

- If i have focused on the input fields the error box were hided
- Scrolltop was working.. But i want smoother scrolltop

```js
var RegisterController = function () {
            $("#register_f").validate({
                rules: {
                    first_name: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                        remote: {
                            url: ajaxurl + 'user/availability',
                            type: "post",
                            data:
                                    {
                                        email: function ()
                                        {
                                            return $('#email').val();
                                        }
                                    }
                        },
                    },
                    password1: {"required": true, minlength: 6},
                    password2: {"required": true, equalTo: "#password1"},
                    "day": "required",
                    "month": "required",
                    "year": "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    first_name: "Firstname is required",
                    email: {
                        required: "Email is required",
                        email: "Invalid Email",
                        remote: $.validator.format("{0} is already taken.")
                    },
                    password1: {
                        required: "Password is Required",
                        minlength: "Password Minimum length is 6 Characters"
                    },
                    password2: {
                        equalTo: "password Does not match",
                        required: "Confirm Password is required"
                    },
                    month: "Please Select month",
                    day: "Please Select day",
                    year: "Please Select year"
                },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                },
                showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

                    if (submitted) {
                        var summary = '<h4>' + this.numberOfInvalids() ;
                        summary += '</ul></div>';
                        $("#errormessages").html(summary);
                        $(document).scrollTop(0);
                        submitted = false;
                    }

                    //--> if you dont want to see the errors in line remove this below line?
                    this.defaultShowErrors();
                },
                invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
                    submitted = true;
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    ajaxindicatorstart();
                    var formdata = global.FormData.serializeArrayToKeyPair($(form).serializeArray());
                    formdata['action'] = 'create';
                    global.CommonAjaxMethod.loadAjaxfunc(ajaxurl + 'register/ajax_request', 'POST', formdata, 'register_success');
                }
            });
            $("#register_f").submit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Smooth Animation :

```
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 1200, 'linear');
```